# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Need to transpose the value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Need advise on how to get the output from the below table:

```
+-----+-------+------------------+
| ID  | Weeks | Hoursofoperation |
+-----+-------+------------------+
| 112 | W     | 7-7              |
| 112 | T     | 8-6              |
| 112 | Th    | 8-6              |
| 112 | Sa    | 9-1              |
| 112 | M     | 9-6              |
| 112 | F     | 9-6              |
+-----+-------+------------------+
```

[image]

Need to get the output value as `MF 9-6, TTh 8-6, W 7-7, Sa 9-1`

[image]

Comment: What particular database engine are we talking about here? SQL dialects and available functions differ.

Comment: Hint: `group_concat()`.

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY, which makes any solution a little more contrived than would otherwise be necessary

Comment: Did you change your engine from mysql to MSSQL? This makes this whole question very confusing now since its tagged as mysql and the answers will surround group concat.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(weeks CHAR(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,hour VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('W','7-7'),
('T','8-6'),
('Th','8-6'),
('Sa','9-1'),
('M','9-6'),
('F','9-6');

SELECT hour
     , GROUP_CONCAT(weeks ORDER BY CASE weeks WHEN 'M' THEN 1 
                                              WHEN 'T' THEN 2 
                                              WHEN 'W' THEN 3 
                                              WHEN 'Th' THEN 4 
                                              WHEN 'F' THEN 5 
                                              ELSE 6 END) x
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY hour;
+------+------+
| hour | x    |
+------+------+
| 7-7  | W    |
| 8-6  | T,Th |
| 9-1  | Sa   |
| 9-6  | M,F  |
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from SQL Server 2017 you can use `STRING_AGG` to aggregate strings in the `SELECT` clause of a `GROUP BY` statement:

```
declare @tmp table ([ID] int, Weeks varchar(50), Hoursofoperation varchar(50))
insert into @tmp values
     (112, 'W'  ,'7-7')
    ,(112, 'T'  ,'8-6')
    ,(112, 'Th' ,'8-6')
    ,(112, 'Sa' ,'9-1')
    ,(112, 'M'  ,'9-6')
    ,(112, 'F'  ,'9-6')

 select [ID], string_agg(res,',') as RESULT from (
     select [ID], string_agg(weeks,'') + ' ' + Hoursofoperation as res
        from @tmp 
        group by [ID], Hoursofoperation
 ) t
 group by [ID]
```

Result:

[image]